# How does Google Maps pronounce streets properly?

Tags: google, siri

How does Google Maps pronounce street names properly, or any maps platform for that matter?

Many words don't have straightforward pronunciations given the orthography/spelling, like "chabot (shaBOW)" or even "christina (krisTEENuh)" or many other words, how do they get the correct pronunciation, is it AI or is there a manual step in there to accomplish it?

I would like to make an open source English pronouncer thingy (take English text in JavaScript and write IPA for it), but for some cases it's impossible (tear drop vs. tear paper, tear has a different pronunciation), but other cases it might be possible but I'm not sure how production systems like Google Maps do it, thinking it's AI or something.